# Running Multiple commands on same Bash via Java Runtime or ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, bash, shell, processbuilder, runtime.exec

I want to run the following commands:-

```
# su - username
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

> enter 3 time to pass null to ssh-keygen options then

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys 
$ chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
$ tar xzf tarpath
$ mv untaredfile ~/somename
```

on shell terminal but via Java i.e I need to automate these commands,in which username and tarpath will be provided dynamically through gui.
I tried executing it with java Runtime but was not able to get the expected result each time I call 
`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("somecommand");` it creates a new instance of that command so all previous command doesn't exists in it.Like switching to user.
can anyone suggest me any solution either a custom shell script or through ProcessBuilder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass to 3 times `enter` for `ssh-keygen -t rsa`, you can try:

```
echo -e "\n\n\n" | ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

or use following command to prevent the passphrase prompt and set the key-pair file path to default path:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -N "" -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

To warp multiple command into one and execute it with a switched user, you can try `su username -c` or other Shell language:

```
su username -c 'ssh-keygen -t rsa -N "" -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa ; cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'
```

To execute the process with Java, you can try use `ProcessBuilder`:

```
String username = "user";
String command = "ssh-keygen -t rsa -N \"\" -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa ; cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys";
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("su", username, "-c", command);
Process process = processBuilder.start();
```

Comment: you can use `su username -c` to replace `bash -c`

Comment: Which part do not work? the `su` command, `ssh-keygen` command or the Java code? I tested the command before I post and I works fine. I updated my answer a little bit. Please see whether it help.